# Adding,removing array elements and accessing via php

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following codes. Each time a user click on a photo, its title is pushed into an array. If he clicks again, the title is removed. I want to be able to access the array later on with php so i can populate a database.

```
function highlight(elem) {
    var e = array();
    if (elem.style.border == '2px solid blue') {
        var index = e.indexOf(elem.parentNode.title);
        e.splice(index, 1);
        elem.style.border = '';
    } else {
        elem.style.border = '2px solid blue';
        e.push(elem.parentNode.title);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? How do i access the javascript array with php?

Comment: The array is recreated every time the function is called, you need to move it to a more persistent scope for starters. It's also uppercase `Array` not `array`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can achieve it?

Comment: I wouldn't do the comparison based on a specific style, but instead do it based on an assigned css class or other html attribute instead. That way, if you ever decide you want those borders to be green instead of blue, you only have to change your stylesheet, not your javascript. Something like element.className.indexOf('selected') != -1

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize the array in a format of your choice (XML, JSON, etc.) and send it back to the server via AJAX. On the server side you have to have a PHP script which accepts the serialized format, can parse it and then perform the DB operations you desire.